# Block users from logging in using their database accounts

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have the following business problem to solve in a big legacy application written in PL/SQL and Oracle Forms 6i:

**Not allow users to log in using their database accounts.**

The whole application has around 50 users who use their database accounts. The audit department doesn’t allow that users know their database accounts passwords.

Rewriting the application to use a new user rights logic (using a table like USERS, only 1 database user, etc.) is out of the question as it’s too much work.

I thought about the following solution to use the existing database users:

Create a table USERS with usernames and new passwords, and somehow use a proxy user. In a package the application will check if the provided password is in line with the table USERS, and then connect as 1 of the 50 database users – so all application logic and user rights can stay the same.

But there is one problem with this workaround – you can’t use „connect” in a package. So I can’t use it.

```
begin
    IF
        p_in_user == USER2 AND p_in_pass == XXX
    THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'conn USER2/Password123'; -- doesn't work, using a proxy neither
    END IF;
END;
```

Does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: This link says what you actually need http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/authid.html

Comment: hi, you can use as below
-> always connect using a hard-coded username to login in to the main .fmx
-> in that landing form create another form wherein you get username and password
-> use that to validate the next step to allow or disallow to the next page
-> however, password expiry and roles has to be managed from within that form/once

Comment: neither in Forms, nor in PLSQL double equation sign might be allowed to use , rather use single equation signs for the boolean expressions in your case.

Comment: try `logon(p_in_user,p_in_pass@db_alias);` within `ON-LOGON` trigger of the Forms.

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Answer (score 1):

> The audit department doesn’t allow that users know their database accounts **passwords**

You can use encripted passwords.

Oracle allow to use encripted passwords through profile settings.

You can use a function to encript a clear password:
the clear password is given to end user
and on oracle database  the user account is created/changed with the encripted password.

The user use his/her clear password to login and during login Oracle conver this to a encripted password for authentication.

Please confirm is this solution is ok, so I can post an example.